# Redux is re-rendering a component when I don't want it to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React and Redux for my website and have ran into an issue. I have this card.
[image: This is the product card]

I can click on the left/right button to see the previous/next image like this:
[image]
But Redux re-renders the component when I click on the +/- button to change the quantity of the product which causes the image to be changed to the original one. What I want is to  make the image stay as it is, but change the quantity at the same time.
[image: product image changes to the original one when I update the quanitity]

There is a lot of code for me to post here, so I will post it on GitHub. [This is the repo](https://github.com/aryan-debug/shopping-cart/tree/master)

I think the main files to look at are `Shop.js`, `ProductCard.js`, `QuantityBox.js` and `app/reducers/ProductSlice.js`

This is the code that is responsible for updating the state:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const ProductSlice = createSlice({
    name: "products",
    initialState: [
            {id: 1, name: "Apple Watch 5", description: "some description", images: ["/product_images/product1_image1.jpeg", "/product_images/product1_image2.jpeg", "/product_images/product1_image3.jpeg"], price: 450, quantity: 0},
            {id: 2, name: "Apple Watch 5", description: "some description", images: ["/product_images/product2_image1.jpeg", "/product_images/product2_image2.jpeg", "/product_images/product2_image3.jpeg"], price: 475, quantity: 0},
            {id: 3, name: "Apple Watch 5", description: "some description", images: ["/product_images/product3_image1.jpeg", "/product_images/product3_image2.jpeg", "/product_images/product3_image3.jpeg"], price: 500, quantity: 0}
        ],
    reducers: {
        incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
            const product_id = action.payload
            const product = state.find(product => product.id === product_id)
            if(product){
                product.quantity++;
            }
        },
        decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
            const product_id = action.payload
            const product = state.find(product => product.id === product_id)
            if(product && product.quantity > 0){
                product.quantity--;
            }
        }
    }
})

export const selectProducts = state => state.products

export const {incrementQuantity, decrementQuantity} = ProductSlice.actions;

export default ProductSlice.reducer
```

Comment: nobody wants to analyse your code to determine where your problem is ... you analyse the code and post the code that is not doing what you expect

Comment: I told you what files have the problem.

Comment: Files? you think the problem exists in 4 files! can you narrow it down a bit - anyway, that's a total of about 100 lines in those files ... so, you can post them here since here they wont' change when you continue *developing* - which would make this question stale very quickly

Comment: The reason I linked those 4 files is because they are connected and work together. But I think the problem is in ProductSlice.js since it is responsible for updating the state of the product.

Comment: but you can post the code here for the above-mentioned reasoning

Comment: I have updated the post to include the code

Comment: The problem is not in your slice, it is in one of the components rerendering or their direct parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `Shop` component. Every time, `Shop` rerenders, you assign new unique `key` properties to your `ProductCard` components. That means that React doesn't find the old one, throws away the old component tree and builds up a completely new one - and resets all component's state in the process.

This is the code you have

```js
        <div id = "product-card-grid">
            {products.map(product => {
                return <ProductCard key = {uniqid()} product_id = {product.id} images = {product.images}/>
            })}
        </div>
```

and instead you should be using stable `key` props:

```js
        <div id = "product-card-grid">
            {products.map(product => {
                return <ProductCard key = {product.id} product_id = {product.id} images = {product.images}/>
            })}
        </div>
```